# Adding covariate to GLM

Tags: generalized-linear-model, ancova

My  response variable is a count data (vse23). My explanatory variables are a combination of continuous (zastska, razkrit, zastveg) and categorical factors (mezo). I did a GLM model of variables that were filtered out after collinearity test.

```
objbukev <- glm(vse23 ~ mezo + zastska + razkrit + zastveg,
            data=objedanje01, family=quasipoisson())
```

One of the variables filtered out because of strong connection to response variable was total density. I was suggested to add total density into the GLM model as a covariate. How do I do that?

Comment: You include its name in the formula, exactly as you included the names of all the other covariates!

Comment: You might also consider whether this variable should be considered a measure of exposure (in which case it would enter as an offset)